# Error message using Azure B2C in claim sub when using CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId: "Not supported currently. Use oid claim."

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

When signing in using LinkedIn as a social provider with Identity Experience Framework the claim `sub` sometimes returns the follwing error message inside the claim values:

```
"Not supported currently. Use oid claim."
```

The error seem to appear randomly and not on each request. Our test accounts get correct claim sub when inspected in https://jwt.ms

When inspecting log files from UserJourneyRecorder in Application Insights the error message was discovered and traced back to our application.

In the policy files the error seems to originate from the claims transformer `CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId`

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" TransformationMethod="CreateStringClaim">
 <InputParameters>
  <InputParameter Id="value" DataType="string" Value="Not supported currently. Use oid claim." />
 </InputParameters>
 <OutputClaims>
   <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sub" TransformationClaimType="createdClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

I believe Azure AD B2C should throw an exception here instead of giving error messages in single claims?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have followed the "[Azure Active Directory B2C: Add LinkedIn as an identity provider by using custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-li-idp)" article, then you can remove the `<OutputClaimsTransformation />` from the "LinkedIn-OAUTH" technical profile:

```xml
<OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
  <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
  <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
  <!-- REMOVE THE FOLLOWING LINE -->
  <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
</OutputClaimsTransformations>
```

If you are using one of [the custom policy starter packs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack), then the "sub" claim should be set to the object identifier for the user object in [the relying party policy file](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAndLocalAccounts/SignUpOrSignin.xml):

```xml
<RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
  <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
    <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
  </TechnicalProfile>
</RelyingParty>
```

Comment: Thanks. Found out that B2C sometimes sends error messages as sub. But using objectId and sub you get oid which seems reliable.